# Unable to Install Application due to Insufficient Storage

Tags: java, android

I am facing error while installing application due to insufficient storage. `Multidex` and `Heap` size modified `vmooptions` already.How to over come this error.I have already did everything related to this:

[image]

Comment: did you install previous app manually?

Comment: That is not an `OutOfMemoryError`. You appear to be out of storage space on the device or emulator on which you are trying to run your app.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on a Emulator you can expand your emulator storage. 
In order to do this close your emulator and open AVD manager.

Next click on the edit icon on the right for your device and look for a button "show advanced settings"

Here you can increase your internal storage and SD card storage. Increasing this should resolve your error.

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the emulator images from the AVD manager, and emulator as well HAXM from the SDK manager. Or simply delete the folder of the emulator from /C:/User/user/.android/avd/"emulators-images". Multidex will won't work as it only works when you have method calls more than 65K! Hope this helps.